# How can I add a search filter for my DataTable in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-data-table-component

I'm looking to enhance my `DataTable` in React by incorporating a search filter.
 I want users to be able to search for specific entries within the table.
 The goal is to allow users to easily search and find specific data within the table. How to implement this?

```
<><ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator>
            <View style={styles.root}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
                    onPress={handleBackButtonClick}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Back</Text>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.searchInput}
                placeholder="Search by customer..."

            />
                    <DataTable style={styles.container}>
                            <DataTable.Header style={styles.tableHeader}>
                                <DataTable.Title>Customer</DataTable.Title>
                                <DataTable.Title>Address</DataTable.Title>
                                <DataTable.Title>Mobile No.</DataTable.Title>
                                <DataTable.Title>Plate No.</DataTable.Title>
                            </DataTable.Header>
                            {displayedCustomers.map((customer, index) =>{
                                return(
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    key={index}
                                    onPress={() => handleRowClick(customer)}
                                    style={[ styles.row,
                                        selectedRow && selectedRow.id === customer.id && styles.selectedRow]} 
                                >
                                <DataTable.Row key={index}>
                                    <DataTable.Cell>{customer.customer}</DataTable.Cell>
                                    <DataTable.Cell>{customer.address}</DataTable.Cell>
                                    <DataTable.Cell>{customer.mobileno}</DataTable.Cell>
                                    <DataTable.Cell>{customer.plateno}</DataTable.Cell>
                                </DataTable.Row>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                )
                                
                            })}

                        
                </DataTable>
                <DataTable.Pagination
                    page={currentPage}
                    numberOfPages={Math.ceil(customers.length / itemsPerPage)}
                    onPageChange={handlePageChange}
                />
            </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a state to hold the search query, and another one to store the filtered data:

```js
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
const [filteredCustomers, setFilteredCustomers] = useState(customers); // Initialize with the full list
```

Now add this function. First it updates `searchQuery` state, then it filters based on the given `text` argment and set this result to `filteredCustomers` state

```js
const handleSearchInputChange = (text) => {
    setSearchQuery(text);
    const filtered = text === "" ? customers : customers.filter(
      (customer) =>
        customer.customer.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()) ||
        customer.address.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()) ||
        customer.mobileno.includes(text) ||
        customer.plateno.includes(text)
    );
    setFilteredCustomers(filtered);
  };
```

You want to execute this logic each time you type in the search `TextInput`

```js
<TextInput
   placeholder="Search by customer..."
   onChangeText={handleSearchInputChange}
   value={searchQuery}
/>
```

Finally, you just need to map through `filtredCustomers` instead of `displayedCustomers`:

```js
{filteredCustomers.map((customer, index) => {
  return (
     <TouchableOpacity
        key={index}
     >
       // ....
     </TouchableOpacity>
  )  
})
```

Comment: The search filter works, but at the start when im not yet typing anything in the text input the table is not displaying the data. I want it to show the data before I type anything in the text input.

Comment: @LesJetskii @LesJetskii you are right, I updated my answer, I've added a condition to let `filtered` equal to `customers` when `text` is an empty string.  also intilize the state to `customers` when the component mount `const [filteredCustomers, setFilteredCustomers] = useState(customers);`

Comment: it only shows all the data when I type something on the text input and delete, but it dont show automatically at the start its blank, I have to delete everything I typed first for all the data to show.

Comment: @LesJetskii add this useEffect: `useEffect(() => {setFilteredCustomers(customers)},[customers])`

Comment: it finally works. Thanks bro